# MiniMagick rows and columns

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, minimagick

In RMagick, I can do `Magick::Image.read(url).first.columns`, but when I try `MiniMagick::Image.open(url).columns`, I get a NoMethodError.

How would I access rows and columns in MiniMagick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MiniMagick::Image.open(url)[:width]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! There's also `MiniMagick::Image.open(path)[:dimensions]` which returns e.g. `[ 123, 456 ]`. You can even do `width, height = MiniMagick::Image.open(path)[:dimensions]` to store them in variables.